# Using List comprehension to establish maximum and minimum values

Tags: list-comprehension

Write a python loop to find the minimum temperature at which a species of plant can survive. The list is provided in the following format: [ {'species': 'Pinus contorta', 'common name': 'Lodgepole Pine', 'min temp (°C)': -40}, {'species': 'Quercus rubra', 'common name': 'Red Oak', 'min temp (°C)': -20}, {'species': 'Betula papyrifera', 'common name': 'Paper Birch', 'min temp (°C)': -30}, {'species': 'Populus tremuloides', 'common name': 'Quaking Aspen', 'min temp (°C)': -35} ]

I tried to find a python loop to find minimum temperature

Answer (score 0):

To find a minimum value you can use `min()` built-in function:

```py
lst = [
    {
        "species": "Pinus contorta",
        "common name": "Lodgepole Pine",
        "min temp (°C)": -40,
    },
    {"species": "Quercus rubra", "common name": "Red Oak", "min temp (°C)": -20},
    {
        "species": "Betula papyrifera",
        "common name": "Paper Birch",
        "min temp (°C)": -30,
    },
    {
        "species": "Populus tremuloides",
        "common name": "Quaking Aspen",
        "min temp (°C)": -35,
    },
]

min_temp = min(lst, key=lambda d: d['min temp (°C)'])
print(min_temp['min temp (°C)'])
```

Prints:

```
-40
```